# How to create model for Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I Have 4 tables on my db

Table "User"

```
id  |  user
-----------
55   |  Jhon    
56   |  Krish   
57   |  Boss
```

Table "Payout"

```
id  |  Payout_Date
------------------
1   |  31.10.2015
2   |  24.10.2015
3   |  17.10.2015
```

Table "Earning"

```
Userid  |  Date       |  Earning
------------------------------------
55      |  31.10.2015 |  5$
56      |  31.10.2015 |  1$
57      |  31.10.2015 |  3$
55      |  30.10.2015 |  5$
56      |  30.10.2015 |  12$
57      |  30.10.2015 |  0$
55      |  29.10.2015 |  5$
56      |  29.10.2015 |  4$
```

When I add a new Payout date (Payout_Date),
I want to find who earn >10$ in their Last payment date between new payout out date, If not pay before that user, his Last Payment_Date is No(get his all earning).

Then add that results to table "Payment" with new Payout_Date to Payment_Date. Their Last Payment_Date is From_Date.

Table "Payment"

```
 id | Userid   |  From_Date  |  Payment_Date |  Earning  |  Status
------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 |  55      |  24.10.2015 |  31.10.2015   |  12$      |  0
  2 |  56      |  24.10.2015 |  31.10.2015   |  17$      |  0
```

How to write that on Codeigniter Controller and Model?

Comment: Have you ever work on  Codeignaiter (codeigniter)?

Comment: Yes, i can create simple cms sites on Codeignaiter

Comment: what you try for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the problem down into pieces: find current payout date, find last time user paid, add earnings since then, filter if > $10 .

Here is a sample of what a view may look like (I did not actually run this so there could be syntax errors)

```
SELECT Earning.Userid, sum(Earning.Earning) earning_since_last
FROM
/* Find current payout Date */
(SELECT MAX(Payout_Date) current_payout_date FROM PAYOUT) as curr_payout,
/* find last time user paid */
(SELECT Userid, MAX(Payout_Date) last_payout_date
  FROM PAYOUT 
  GROUP BY Userid) last_payout,
Earning
WHERE Earning.date <= curr_payout.current_payout_date
  and last_payout.Userid = Earning.Userid
  and earning.date > last_payout.last_payout_date
GROUP BY Earning.Userid
HAVING SUM(Earning.Earning) >= 10
```

Comment: when i write function payout (), how to save that result in "payment" table?

Comment: You can add a "MIN(Earning.date) as from_date, curr_payout.current_payout_date" to the SELECT clause and then you have all the columns to "INSERT" into your payout table.  You'll also have to set the "Status" column appropriately